# how does rabbitmq set_permission command use our inputs

Tags: permissions, rabbitmq

rabbitmq docs says for setting permission for a user on a virtual host you need to give 3 inputs first one is for configuration second one is for write and third one is for read.
can somebody explain what does configuration mean in this command?
does this 3 inputs works for exchanges or are they used for indicating which queues user can work with? if it is both can you give me an example for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [RabbitMQ's doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#authorisation):

1. Configure: `The configure operations create or destroy resources, or alter their behaviour.`
2. The three inputs work for everything the user interacts with. Different operations on different resource types require different permissions. The permissions are checked when a user tries to perform an operation on a resource.
3. For example, if your user wants to be able to create an exchange with an Alternate Exchange, it must have configure+read permissions for the exchange and write permission for the Alternate Exchange. You have the complete table in the link above